# Unable to push applications into Bluemix using CF CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

When we try to push applications in Bluemix using CF CLI we get the below message that the user is not authorized

"Server error, status code: 403, error code: 10003, message: You are not authorized to perform the requested action"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here seems to be with privileges of the user on the Space where the application was pushed.
After providing 'Developer' role to the space the user was able to push the application.